# sqlite method return query output of rails console in render proccess

Tags: sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

Specs :
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS i686
, Ruby 2.1.5 , Rails 4.2.7 , sqlite 3 , devise 4.3

when I loop through each `user` in `users` , it's rendering the users + a query output from rails console.

Devise model name : User .

controller name: users.

I tried this code:

users_controller.rb

```
def index
    @users = User.all()
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :users, only: [:index, :show]
```

views/users/index.html.erb

```
<%= @users.each do |user| %>
    <%= link_to user do %>
        <li>
            <img src="images/avatar.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="user_overview">
                <h2><%= user.title %></h2>
                <p class="posts_count">1 post</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view, just remove `=` from `<%= @users.each do |user| %>`.

It will become like:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <%= link_to user do %>
        <li>
            ...
            ...
            ...
            ...
        </li>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

`=` in `erb` is used for displaying the content that's why your loop is displaying the `enumerator`.

Read more details on [Expression Printing Tags](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/5.0/lang_template_erb.html#expression-printing-tags)